# Ehcache with REST

Tags: java, rest, ehcache

I am trying to implement Ehcache in my program,How can I configure Ehcache?Where Should I write the logic,in Impl class?what are all the configurations for that?Where should I put he Ehcache XML?I am new to this,Is there any examples other than Ehcache official website?Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questoin is overly broad, but here are few tips:

1. Decide whether you want to cache service layer or web layer

   1. If service layer, avoid EhCache dependencies as much as possible. For instance [Spring 3.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) introduced great caching abstraction driven by annotations.
   2. If you want to cache web layer, EhCache provides nice [web filter](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/web-caching) that intercepts all requests and caches the results. Use with care!
2. Remember about cache invalidation and consistency
3. Think about distribution
4. Collect statistcs and monitor them

Comment: Is it possible to connect the service layer EhCache configuration to the `Cache Server`'s REST api? (Whether using Spring's setup like I am OR raw EhCache)